# How to use decrypted password in struts config datasource

Tags: struts-1, struts-config

I am using unencrypted DB password in Struts config datasource block, but for security concerns I would like to use encrypted password over there. I am not sure how would that work when the application is loaded and checks for DB connectivity. I am also using Apache Commons DBCP.

Is there anyway to automatically decrpyt the DB password from struts config? I am using struts 1.

```
<data-source type="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
<set-property property="username" value="userid"/>
<set-property property="password" value="encryptedpassword"/>
```

Comment: The struts config is not accessible from the browser when deployed in an application server at all. Why is this a concern?

Comment: not sure though abt clients requirement but because of security concerns this is needed.

Comment: what security concern exactly?

Comment: I can think of several, most notably PCI, or common sense.  Why would you leave the database password lying around on the file system.

Comment: our application is deployed on a server where the server management team having access will be able to see the passwords easily in addition to the developers. So need to know if there is any way to avoid this.

Comment: Do you have to use struts config to maintain the password?  Could you use a different datasource management process? Could you include the struts file and encrypt that?  It might be easier to to encrypt an entire file than adapt struts to read the field